# How to access components inside a project folder?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I am writing my first VB.NET app and encountered some difficulties.
I added a folder to the project called 'AppData' in which i added a new ADO.NET Entity Data Model (database first). 
my first problem is that i was able to create the component but i cannot see the generated model classes (when doing the same thing in a c# project I don't have this problem)

The second problem is when trying to access the folder 'AppData' which I created.
in c# I would just declare an instance by referencing the folder name first: `AppData.SomeClassName instance;`

but when trying to do a similar thing in VB.NET like: `Dim instance As AppData.SomeClassName` I get a compile error that says : `'AppData' is not declared. it may be inaccessible due to its protection level`

Thanks a lot to whom who could help.

Comment: Your code doesn't really know anything about folders. In C#, if you add a type code file in a folder then that type will be placed within a namespace named after the folder.  In VB, everything will be in the default namespace unless you specify otherwise, so you would just use the type(s) in VB with no regard for the folder.

Comment: Oh I see! thanks a lot for the quick explanation!

Comment: I still would like to know how to resolve my first problem

Comment: I just tested exactly what you said and it worked exactly as I said, so there should be no problem as far as I can tell.